# smallest sigma algebra can be obtained by countable operations?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$. Then $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$ is given by the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\mathcal{A}$.

Is it true that $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ exactly consists of the sets which can be obtained by countable union & intersection, and complement of the sets in $\mathcal{A}$?

For example: Is it true that every Borel set can be obtained by countable union & intersection, and complement of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: When you say "obtained", do you mean that you are allowing countable unions of countable intersections of countable unions, etc.?

Comment: Every Borel set can be obtained by a tree of countable unions, countable intersections and complements whose branches terminate at open sets, but the tree might be quite deep (any depth below $\omega_1$.)

Comment: What @DavidMoews says extends to arbitrary generated $\sigma$-algebras. This follows from the fact that if $B\in\sigma(\mathcal{F})$, then there exists countable $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ such that $B\in\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ and the fact that every countably generated $\sigma$-algebra is generated by a real-valued function with the codomain being endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Actually I didn't explained it well. But I'm just thinking of it as follows. From $\mathcal{A}$, let $\mathcal{A}(1)$ be the set obtained by countable unions, countable intersections, complements of $\mathcal{A}$. Similarly, $\mathcal{A}(n+1)$ be defined from $\mathcal{A}(n)$. So we get $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{A}(1) \subset \mathcal{A}(2) \subset \cdots$. Then is it true that $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$=$\mathcal{A}(N)$ for some $N$? Or $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\cup \mathcal{A(n)}$?

Comment: And I guess that David answered "no" to my comment.

Comment: In general, you have to go on and let ${\cal A}(\omega)=\cup_n {\cal A}(n)$, let ${\cal A}(\omega+1)$ be all sets obtained by countable unions, intersections and complements of sets in ${\cal A}(\omega)$, and so on.  The sequence goes on through the countable ordinals.  Taking the union of ${\cal A}(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha<\omega_1$ will always give you $\sigma({\cal A})$.  In some cases the process might terminate earlier.

Comment: *The Joy of Sets* by Devlin contains a very readable exposition of the topic.